# Insert in table, Sequence.nextval not working

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I have the following 3 tables,

**Data_Excel** contains the names, address, city and source of person; 
**Person table** has the name and ID;  
I need to insert into **person_location** the address source, address, city and ID...

I am using the following query :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq
START WITH 6571
MINVALUE 6571
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 100
```

```
INSERT INTO Person (id,Name,source) 
Select (seq.nextval),p_name,source 
FROM Data_Excel 
WHERE P_Name NOT IN 
(SELECT name FROM Person) 
GROUP BY P_Name,P_Address,P_city,Source 
HAVING count(*) < 2;
```

but I get the following error.
I am using seq because ID is the primary key in persons but its not auto incrementing. I also tried that but there was an error :

```
02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here" 
*Cause:    The specified sequence umber (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate 
here in the statement. 
*Action:    emove the sequence number.
```

[image: I have the following 3 tables, Data_Excel contains the names, address, city and source of person; Person table has the name and ID; I need to insert into person_location the address source, address, city and ID...where ID comes from person table and name that exist against the id should be matched in the data_excel table to get all the details]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try moving the sequence out of the grouping query:

```
INSERT INTO Person (id,Name,source) 
SELECT seq.nextval, p_name,source FROM (
Select p_name,source 
FROM Data_Excel 
WHERE P_Name NOT IN 
(SELECT name FROM Person) 
GROUP BY P_Name,P_Address,P_city,Source 
HAVING count(*) < 2
);
```

Comment: It works Thanks, if i have to do it generically like whenever i am going to insert a value i do it like max(id)+1 from person table, How can i do that?

Comment: some thing like this:
CREATE SEQUENCE seq
START WITH (select max(id)+1 from person)
MINVALUE (select max(id)+1 from person)
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 100

Comment: I guess (because I have no Oracle here to check), instead of `SELECT seq.nextval, p_name,source FROM` you could use `SELECT ROWNUM + (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Person), p_name,source FROM`. If it works (try it), then be warned that it is deemed bad practice because: when executed by multiple clients at exactly the same time the statements may get the same `MAX(id)` and produce duplicate keys leading to a duplicate key error.

Comment: i tried that in select statement but it returns only once for e.g for 6572 for all 3000 rows in result, how can i make sure this query runs for each row?